# Mercurial Repository Name Not Coming

Tags: mercurial

I have created a local repository and cloned it to remote mercurial server . And when I am checking it through my web interface of mercurial server I am getting "__NAME_ _" instead of my mercurial repository name .

I know I just need to modify a file. But I am confused which file to modify .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to show the correct description is an `hgrc` file in the repository's `.hg` folder.  The file should contain the following:

```
[web]
description=Repository description
```

The help for the `web` section of `hgrc` is [here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#web).

I agree with Ry4an though, it looks like an installation problem on the server to me because just cloning the repository as you described should show the correct name with "Unknown" as the description.

Comment: Thanks for the help ,it(i.e. editing the hgrc) really helped me to resolve this issue . Also you have provided a useful resource for hgrc web use . Thanks Again :)

Comment: Don't keep us in suspence @Subhransu.  What did you change to get the names in there? Description I know ,but I've never not seen names autofill.

Comment: @Ry4an , As I have already mentioned in the "comment in your answer", the other portals are created by someone else . Well their could be a script(to add hgrc) which may be triggered after "hg init" in the server .

Answer (score 2):

Something must be wrong w/ the "remote mercurial server".  From the look of it you're running 'hgweb' and possibly it's a version of the script that's older than the underlying Mercurial installation?  Try making sure the hgweb.cgi (or hgweb.wsgi) in use on that server is current and corresponds to the Mercurial installation on that server.

Comment: if the hgweb.cgi is older then how i am getting other mercurials repo  name(i.e. webportal and websupport, created by someone else) .I think its problem in way of creating mercurial repo.

Comment: The odd thing is that it should always show the repository name no matter what which is probably why @Ry4an suggests that there is an installation problem.  I just did a test on our server where I created a folder and refreshed the page - it didn't show the new folder because it wasn't a repository.  I created a `.hg` folder in that folder and refreshed - it did show and had the correct name so even with an invalid repository, it should show the name.